# Find available languages for knowledge base articles in soql

Tags: soql, knowledge, translation

I want to retrieve our stored knowledgebase articles regardless of the language they are in. However querying KnowledgeArticleVersion using SOQL requires a language be specified in the where clause or it produces an error.
I don't want to have to separately query every possible language that might exist, is there a way to find out what translations for an article exist?

Comment: How many languages do you have?

Comment: At the moment only 3 I believe but that is likely to increase over time

Comment: You can always put the languages in an OR or in a list and say Languages IN ('.....'). Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, the api won't let you do that. You can only specifiy one language at a time. It seems like a really weird restriction.

Comment: [Always filter on a single value of Language. However, in SOQL, you can filter on more than one Language if there is a filter on Id or KnowledgeArticleId.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

So if you set the ID's as a list of all ID's then you can filter on more than one language

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that you can do it if you filter on KnowledgeArticleId as well as Id. That's perfect thanks. If you want to put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per salesforce documentation on KnowledgeArticleId

[Always filter on a single value of Language. However, in SOQL, you can filter on more than one Language if there is a filter on Id or KnowledgeArticleId.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

It seems that you can filter on more than one language if you set an ID filter, simply add all the ID's then filter on the languages :)

Comment: Hi @raymond,

Could you please share the query that worked for you, I have a similar requirement